# Bottom bracket question?

Tags: bottom-bracket

I have a sram red crank set that uses a bb30 bottom bracket I want to use this crank set on my fixed gear bike wich needs a threaded bottom bracket would I be able to use this bb that works for my frame and bb?

[image: Picture of bracket]

Answer (score 6):

No, that's a BB386EVO bottom bracket. There is no way to do this with a normal BB30 crank because the spindle isn't long enough.

BB386EVO cranks are 30mm spindle cranks with longer spindles that can go in both BB30 frames and threaded shell frames with BBs such as the ones you link to.